# Is there a systematic approach to retrieve the closed-form analytic function from its Taylor series?

Tags: reference-request, taylor-expansion, closed-form

Suppose one has found the complete Taylor series of a certain function during research. Afterwards, one would like to find the corresponding closed-form expression of this function -- assuming it is analytic. What are the different ways to go about that process? I know there is a bag of tricks, including multiplying the Taylor series with $x$ or differentiating it to try to find a Taylor series that is already-well-known. But these seem like ad-hoc approaches to me. So my questions are:

1. Is there a systematic approach to find the closed-form expression of some Taylor Series for which the general term is known?
2. Suppose one has found a closed-form expression for which the Taylor Series matches the series you have found for the first $k$ terms, but afterwards they differ. Does a method exist with which one can adjust the closed form in such a way that its Taylor series will coincide with the series you've found after the $k$'th term as well? (So it does necessarily not have to wholly coincide with the series one is after, but at least one get get successively closer to it by means of some iterative method of adjustment of the closed-form)
3. Is there an overview article of the aforementioned “bag of tricks” to retrieve the closed-form by means of educated guesses to adjust the Taylor Series to make it look like a series that is well-known?

Comment: I would even doubt that a closed form exists in general. If you differntiate the series and the result is somehow related to the given series, you sometimes can derive the closed-form. Maybe, it gets a bit easier if we demand that a closed form exists for the coefficients, should they be, lets say, the prime numbers, I would not expect that a closed form exists.

Comment: There are many many analytic functions that have no "closed form expression." Until someone gave a name to them, those included sine, cosine, exp, erf, ...

Comment: @Peter Yes, it can certainly be the case that the closed form does not exist. Let's assume that it does exist though. We also suppose that a closed form for the coefficients exists -- that's what I somewhat idiosyncratically meant with "complete Taylor Series"

Comment: @JohnHughes True. But like I said to Peter, let's suppose for the sake of the question that a closed form does exist, and we would like to express it in terms of functions that we have already named and about which we know quite a bit by now, including the Maclaurin series found over here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of summands. If you got a closed-form expression for the finite summation problem ($n\in\mathbb{N}$), you could try to calculate the limit of that expression for $n\to\infty$.

Look for "Hypergeometric Summation", "Summation in finite terms" and "Symbolic summation".

There are i. a. decision algorithms for that.

Read e.g. the chapter "Symbolic Summation" in Bona, Miklos: Handbook of Enumerative Combinatorics. Chapman and Hall/CRC 2015.

There is a theory or an algorithm from Michael Karr:
Karr, Michael: Summation in finite terms. J. Assoc. Comp. Mach. 28 (1981) (2)305-350
[Karr, Michael: Theory of Summation in Finite Terms. J. Symbolic Computation 1 (1985) (3) 303-315](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717185800389)

And there is a theory or an algorithm from Carsten Schneider:
Look for
Schneider Summation
and for
Schneider sums